# Async shell command can't find command

Tags: shell-command, async, rust, debian

I have installed the Rust programming language (Debian). Now i can compile and run programs from terminal (with the `cargo build` and `cargo run` commands), but not from inside emacs. The cargo compiler stays on my system in `/home/me/.cargo/bin/cargo` and emacs is not looking there to find the interpreter. I get this error `/bin/bash: cargo: command not found` by running `M-x &, cargo build`. So how can i tell emacs the address of cargo binary, or is it better to send the binary to the address emacs looks in?

Comment: I think you forgot to add `export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"` to your bashrc ? You should also try [cargo.el](https://github.com/kwrooijen/cargo.el).

Comment: `export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"` is already in bashrc. I have installed the cargo.el package, same error. Emacs can't find the cargo binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up the `exec-path` variable so that emacs finds the cargo binary at `~/.cargo/bin`:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":" (expand-file-name "~/.cargo/bin")))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path (list (expand-file-name "~/.cargo/bin"))))
```